# Can I use an excel formula to extract the link location of a hyperlink which has been generated by using concatenation in a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Need help Can I use an excel formula to extract the link location of a hyperlink  which has been generated by using concatenation in a cell?

Comment: probably, you need to show us what your input looks like and your expected output. Generally, we only troubleshoot errors in attempted solutions...

Comment: [Check this link may help U](https://superuser.com/questions/1551844/excel-hyperlinked-dynamic-index/1551948#1551948) ☺

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation is a formula to Excel whether it uses one of the several concatenation functions or just the union method (=A1&A2&...etc.). So you can use `FORMULATEXT()` to get the formula as a string and then extract the portion you need.

More easily though, just use the inputs you use to build the hyperlink to separately build the link location you desire. Excel doesn't mind you using material twice.

By the way, gns100's comment isn't just because no one really wants to do a lazybones's (not you, just speaking generally here) work for free, it has at least a couple other reasons behind it. First, **for the most part**, no one learns without trying to fight through a thing. Second, as in life itself, in Excel, an exact answer is dependent upon so many, many factors that one needs a pretty darn good idea of the particulars before answering. Otherwise, he does the work, writes an answer, then sees the poster leaving a comment (or worse, editing a comment into his question and not noticing that) saying, "Yeah, but... there's this other factor..." and does the work to incorporate that only to see, again, "Yeah, but... there's this other factor..." and that **doesn't cut it**.

I must admit, I am surprised, very surprised, you can build a hyperlink, but not either extract what you need as I suggest above, or use the same inputs to separately build what you need here, as I suggest above.