# EXCEL : Hyperlinked dynamic index

Tags: worksheet-function, hyperlink, google-spreadsheets, links

I found below formula to generate a dynamic index in spreadsheet.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet!$A:$A,SMALL(IF(ISTEXT(Sheet!$A:$A),ROW(Sheet!$A:$A),""),ROW(Sheet!A1))),"")
```

Is there a way i could add hyperlinks to the index generated by the above formula so that i can have a dynamic and linked index.
I am looking forward to a solution which will work in google spreadsheets.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: You may call this an "index", but it's just a list of cells with text from another column. What kind of hyperlink behaviour are you after? Does the hyperlink exist in column A and you want to have that same hyperlink in your "Index"?  Or do you want to click on a cell in your "index" and it takes you to the cell in column A?  Both would involve VBA. It cannot be done with worksheet formulas. Why did you tag with google spreadsheets? Please don't mix tags for different products. The solutions will not be the same.

Comment: I am looking for a way , such that clicking on a cell in the "index"  takes me to the corresponding cell in column A (of the sheet upon which the "index" is built .) . Sorry about the tagging.. is the solution going to be different for google sheet ?

Comment: Yes. Google Sheets and Excel are two different products. The basic things will work in either, but advanced formulas like this will be very different. So, before you waste people's time, what is the platform you want a solution for?

Comment: @teylyn the formula mentioned in description worked in google sheets as well. I am looking forward for the solution in google sheets.

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/H2kFpJs) exact requirement

Comment: Please edit your question to add clarification. People will not read through a wall of comments to figure out what you are really asking. That needs to be in your question. Use the site system for screenshots. If you don't have enough reputation to display the screenshot, someone will edit your question and show it.

Answer (score 1):

*This method will help you to create Hyperlink for the list of extracted/Indexed vales:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- This lookup and creates hyperlink to the first match name.
- An array (CSE) formula in cell `F63`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address", INDEX($C$63:$C$67, MATCH($E63,$A$63:$A$67,0))), INDEX($C$63:$C$67, MATCH($E63,$A$63:$A$67,0))),"")}
  ```

---

**::Edited::**

***Caveat:***

*Below shown method works with all versions of EXCEL,, originally OP is using Google Online Version and the OP bring it in the notice few minutes back only. So readers consider it for Excel only.*

[image]

- Write this array (CSE) formula in Sheet1 Cell `L1`.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address",INDEX(Sheet2!$I$1:$I$5,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$I$1:$I$5<>"",ROW(Sheet2!$I$1:$I$5)),ROWS(Sheet2!$A1:$A$1)))),INDEX(Sheet2!$I$1:$I$5,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$I$1:$I$5<>"",ROW(Sheet2!$I$1:$I$5)),ROWS(Sheet2!$A1:$A$1)))),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish an array (CSE) formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: My exact requirement is like this [link](https://ibb.co/H2kFpJs) . I am able to create the dynamic list of sheets column contents on another sheet using the formula in the question desription.

Comment: @Suyash,, now check edited part of my post,, will help U ☺

Comment: thanks for your input . I am able to create link using the formula you provided, but the link does not take me to the linked cell upon clicking. [link](https://ibb.co/Jrv4qwC)

Comment: @Suyash,, nothing wrong with my formula,, I always test command and load the real screen shot,, better U upload your file to examine & fix it!

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ybpPzuQ5gOeWT6safEe1SRTg4HbKzoaAEc2VmcAl9zk/edit?usp=sharing) . please check it once... the concern is that clicking the hyperlink does not take to the linked cell.

Comment: @Suyash,,, I need the editable version,,, **and let me clear that in Sheet 1 cell A1,, you have used old formula not what I've suggested,,, the array formula,,, I think need to read properly,,,**  time is precious for me & others.. *READ CAREFULLY THE EDITED PART OF MY POST & FIND THE FORMULA, is WORKING & USE it.*

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ybpPzuQ5gOeWT6safEe1SRTg4HbKzoaAEc2VmcAl9zk/edit?usp=sharing)  I ve used the formula provided by you in sheet 1's L1 column and the content is entered in sheet 2's I column , exactly as is provided by you in the screenshot.

Comment: @Suyash,, when you move mouse over L1, you get one dialogue and cell address `#Shee2!$I$1`,, click that,, it works,,, and [edit] your post and add that you are using Google Sheet,, not Excel also add new TAG to the question `Google Sheet`.

Comment: @Suyash,,, [Check this, I've downloaded & tested](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/oxep1f9s654hazx7io3ff/Untitled-spreadsheet.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=c9v7hm4jc03xnqlfwyfs6uqmj) it's working !! And Link at L1 is working too.

Comment: It is working in the downloaded versions of the file. I agree with you.

Comment: But it does not seem to be working in the online google spreadsheet, might be a limitation of the online viewer. thanks for your support.

Comment: @Suyash,, downloaded version is your file,,, working at both A1 & L1,,,, for original I've written how it works, read comment above !!

Comment: There is no response upon Clicking on the The dialogue with cell address `#Shee2!$I$1`. (which come when moving the mouse over the cell ) . Here's a short clip which shows what I seeing on my screen [link](https://gofile.io/d/n931jS)